# « En » dans « Tu en es où ? »

Tags: expressions-idiomatiques, locutions, en

Je ne me rappelle pas la source mais j'ai lu quelque part:

> – Tu as fini ta thèse ?
>
> – Non !
>
> – Tu en es où ?
>
> – À la fin.

Je sais qu'il existe des locutions où *en* n'a pas de valeur précise.
Est-ce un tel cas ici ? Sinon, pourquoi l'emploi de *en* dans la tournure  'Tu en es où' ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Dans des cas ambigus il est possible de compléter la phrase :

> Tu en es où, de ta thèse ?

*En* renvoie à la situation courante, qui est ici précisée à l'aide du complément « de ta thèse ». Il n'est cependant pas possible d'utiliser « être de quelque chose » (avec ce sens) sans le pronom. C'est l'une de ces locutions formées autour de *en*.

---

If there were any ambiguity, you could complete the sentence as follows:

> Tu en es où, de ta thèse ?

*En* stands for the current situation, made precise here with the complement *de ta thèse*. But you can't use “être de quelque chose” (with this meaning) skipping the pronoun. It's one of those locutions formed around *en*.

Comment: on dit plutôt "dans ta thèse" que "de ta thèse"; en effet, le 1er cas montre l'emplacement où l'on est rendu pour la rédaction de la thèse, tandis que le 2nd indique ... jenesaisquoi !