# Expressions idiomatiques avec "en"

Tags: expressions, prépositions, expressions-idiomatiques, en

Il y a des expressions françaises où *en* n'est clairement pas un remplacement de *de + objet*. De plus, l'objet introduit par *de* peut paraître explicitement avec ces expressions (autrement dit, *en* ici n'est pas un pronom complément). Par exemple :

> J'*en* ai assez *de* cette hypocrisie.

(Où *en* n'a pas la même fonction que dans *Cette hypocrisie me fatigue. J'en ai assez.* Voir aussi [cette question](https://french.stackexchange.com/q/49280/9870)).

> J'en ai marre *de* la pluie.

> Je m'*en* veux *de* lui avoir fait du mal.

S'agit-il simplement d'expressions idiomatiques (à savoir/mémoriser) ou *en* a-t-il une autre fonction ? Pourrait-on envisager l'utilisation d'un double *en* (un idiomatique et l'autre remplaçant l'objet ?)

[Une question similaire](https://french.stackexchange.com/q/6704/9870)

Comment: See https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/30706/on-en-veut-pourquoi-en ; https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/22726/what-is-the-origin-of-en-vouloir ; https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/31268/en-dans-tu-en-es-o%c3%b9 ; https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/30678/la-fonction-de-en-dans-en-arriver-l%c3%a0

Comment: Also https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/29775/vous-en-souhaitant ; https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/49907/fonction-de-en-dans-un-discours-voici-comment-nous-agissons-en-europ%c3%a9ens ; https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/31298/il-en-est-de-m%c3%aame

Comment: @Dimitris merci pour ces liens. Mais je ne crois pas qu'il repondent à ma question: soit ils s'agissent de le sense des expressions (plotôt que la fonction d'*en'*), soit il contient des reponses contradictoires: c'est un pronom complement... non, ce n'est pas un pronom complement.

Comment: Désolé ; juste une note en marge de+le => du (sens).

Comment: Il y a des expressions avec en et y figées. On doit les apprendre telles quelles. Ex. Je m’en vais ; J’en ai marre ; Je lui en veux ;  Il s’en prend toujours à moi=he always picks on me ; Il s’en fait= il s’inquiète ; Tu t’y prends mal ; Je n’y suis pour rien ; Ça y est...

Answer (score 1):

Y et EN se trouvent dans nombreuses expressions figées. Dans ce cas y et en  ne remplacent rien et ne remplissent pas leur rôle habituel (remplacer un complément). On doit apprendre ces expressions telles quelles. En voici certaines.

[image]

Source : https://ddotb.wordpress.com/2015/09/14/expressions-avec-y-et-en/

Une deuxième liste :

[image]

Source : http://languagelearningbase.com/88081/expressions-idiomatiques-contenant-en-et-y

Comment: Je l'interprète comme ça : il s'agit d'un petit nombre d'expressions bien defini - certainement pas suffisamment grand pour généraliser comme un regle de grammaire.

Comment: « En être » a une connotation d'appartenance à un groupe minoritaire  : Argot des années 60 : «  — Il est de la jaquette. — Ah, *Il en est* lui-aussi ! »

Answer (score 1):

On the contrary, in your example this is wrong. But the reason you do not perceive it is that this particular usage is actually a redundant usage which is fully accepted; "en" actually replaces "de cette hypocrisie". The usage without "en" is rare but fully acceptable, and it might some day replace the redundant usage, although ngrams do not show that. Here is the case "(en) ai assez de cette".

[image]

[page of examples corresponding to the construction without "en"](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22j%27ai%20assez%20de%20cette%22&tbm=bks&lr=lang_fr)

*A few examples from that page*

- (2022) J'ai assez de cette existence de crétin et de dupe que vous me faites mener depuis vingt ans... Oui, fini tout cela!... Je m'en irai... J'irai vivre n'importe où... avec des honnêtes gens...
- (2013) J'ai assez de cette jeunesse corrompue, avachie, hystérique, vide, combinarde, prétentieuse, vaniteuse, bestiale, roquets ou singes toujours prêts à planter leurs crocs dans la main qui les flatte.
- (1976) J'ai assez de cette existence... Sur la route de la fontaine, j'ai rencontré des jeunes gens qui se sont moqués de moi... J'exige que tu me procures une esclave. Quand j'en aurai une, c'est elle que j'enverrai chercher de l'eau à la
- (1845) Ami, dit Adeline en élevant la voix , j'ai assez de cette histoire - là . Je n'aime pas les moines , et votre Chabot tout le premier .
- (2015) Mon Dieu, comme j'ai assez de cette boutique et comme je pense à notre bel appartement et à tous les gens heureux qui vous voient, si au moins je pouvais descendre en ville aujourd'hui !
- (1978) Aujourd'hui, je ne suis pas en forme et j'ai assez de cette gymnastique. J'ai faim aussi. Je n'ai rien absorbé ce matin avant de partir car j'étais en retard comme d'habitude. Oui, j'ai très faim et tellement envie de m'asseoir

In all cases, if you wanted to emphasize the fact you could repeat the words except for the word that names what you are fed up with; but you must add "en", which is interpreted as usual.

- J'ai assez de ce poulet au chocolat tous les jours… J'en ai assez !

So as to get a good idea of this difference, you might study a few of the exemples on [this page](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22j%27en%20ai%20assez%20de%20cette%22&tbm=bks&lr=lang_fr). You are free to use this redundant form, which will not result at all in your French  sounding erratic, or you may use the purer but rarer form without "en".

These explanations are confirmed by the TLFi: "en" appears between parentheses  in the construction.

> ([TLFi](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/assez)) B.− (En) avoir assez de qqn, de qqc., de + inf.
> • Hutinel la trouve mieux. Il veut qu'on attende à mardi ou mercredi pour la ponction, s'il y a lieu. On lui cite qu'elle a assez du lait. Renard, Journal,1901, p. 636.
> •  Je crois que son mari en a assez de la cohabitation avec ta mère. Mauriac, Le Mystère Frontenac,1933, p. 178.